# Ping ZigBee Routers to see if they're online

Tags: python, networking, xbee, zigbee

I currently have a ZigBee network setup as following;

1 Coordinator, responsible for managing the network and handle incoming dataframes.
2 Routers, placed on location, that communicatie with all other ZigBee nodes using the mesh-network.

I am looking for a way to send a ping from the Coordinator, to see if the routers are online or offline. I want to use this in case of a power failure; to check if the network is fully functional.

I am using Python to handle my Coordinator.

I am aware that there is a Python library available for use with XBee products. Since I use XBee products I use this library. However, I couldnt find a fitting solution just yet.

Link to library: https://code.google.com/p/python-xbee/

Is there any solution available to succesfully ping the network, see which nodes are available, and return this in a variable?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe perform node discovery (the `ATND` command)?  Or send unicast remote AT commands to each node periodically and make sure they respond?

If you're trying to remain ZigBee compliant, you'd probably pick a ZDP (ZigBee Device Profile) request (like one to query active endpoints) and send that.